# Remove duplicate from the nested Object of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to remove the duplicate from the below array of Object which has some nested element with array

Below is my array.

```
      {
        field: ‘A’,
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajd', 'ajd', 'kajd'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘A’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['123', '4', '45', '94'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: 'A',
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajd', 'ajd', ''],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘A’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['123', '4', '45'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘Z’,
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajdm', 'askjd', 'kajd'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘Z’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['13', '123', '1823'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘Z’,
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajdm', 'askjd', ''],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ’Z’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['13', '123', ''],
        },
      },
    ];
```

and I want to keep the **1st key** under each **field**
i.e 1st key_A under field 'A' and 1st key_B under field 'A'

same for field 'Z'

so final o/p:

```
      {
        field: ‘A’,
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajd', 'ajd', 'kajd'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘A’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['123', '4', '45', '94'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘Z’,
        value: {
          key_A: ['ajdm', 'askjd', 'kajd'],
        },
      },
      {
        field: ‘Z’,
        value: {
          key_B: ['13', '123', '1823'],
        },
      },
    ];
```

I tried some logic with filter looping over the array but for the nested could not figure out a logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation using the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36744732/13583510). the `findIndex` gives the index of first element that satisfies the condition and the `filter` therefore filters out the first elements that satisfies the condition.
`Object.keys(t.value)[0]` gives either `"key_A"` or `"key_B"` depending on the element

```js
let arr =    [  {        field: 'A',        value: {          key_A: ['ajd', 'ajd', 'kajd'],        },      },      {        field: 'A',        value: {          key_B: ['123', '4', '45', '94'],        },      },      {        field: 'A',        value: {          key_A: ['ajd', 'ajd', ''],        },      },      {        field: 'A',        value: {          key_B: ['123', '4', '45'],        },      },      {        field: 'Z',        value: {          key_A: ['ajdm', 'askjd', 'kajd'],        },      },      {        field: 'Z',        value: {          key_B: ['13', '123', '1823'],        },      },      {        field: 'Z',        value: {          key_A: ['ajdm', 'askjd', ''],        },      },      {        field:'Z',        value: {          key_B: ['13', '123', ''],        },      },    ];

let res = arr.filter((v, i, self) =>
  i === self.findIndex((t) => (
    t.field === v.field && Object.keys(t.value)[0] === Object.keys(v.value)[0]
  ))
)

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I had seen the exact solution and even tried the same just missed the [0] there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
interface Address {
    address: string,
    city: string,
    state: string,
    zip: number
}

const addresses: Address[] = [
    {
        address: "1234 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "4444 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "5555 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "6666 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    },
    {
        address: "7777 Main St",
        city: "San Diego",
        state: "CA",
        zip: 92014
    }
]

function delay(time: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time));
  }


const apiCaller = async(addr: Address) => { 
    await delay(0.5);
    return `Got ${addr.address}`
}

const apiRunner = async () => {
    const results: PromiseSettledResult<string>[] = [];

    let promises: Promise<string>[] = [];

    for (const address of addresses) {
        promises.push(apiCaller(address));
        if (promises.length >= 10) {
            const rez = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
            results.push(...rez);
            promises = [];
        }
    }

    if (promises.length > 0) {
        const rez = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
        results.push(...rez);
    }

    return results;

}
```